# Review URL-prettifying .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

Can anyone please review the following `.htaccess` file and let me if it is correctly put together?

What I think it does:

- So it direct to a custom 404 page
- Remove the extensions from the end of the urls (example `.php`)
- Remove `/index`
- I don't really understand what the final rule does, can anyone please explain it if could?

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /404 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# Remove enter code here.php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP 
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# Remove /index 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
# The trailing slash is removed in a next request, so be efficient and dont put it on there at all 
RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1 [R=301,L] 

# Remove slash if not directory 
# By puting the L-flag here, the request gets redirected immediately 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ 
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L] 

# Add .php to access file, but don't redirect 
# On some hosts RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f will be true, even if 
# no such file exists. Be safe and add an extra condition 
# There is no point in escaping a dot in a string 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/|\.php)$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
```

Comment: in order for your custom error page to be directed properly you need to put a URL after it and remove the duplicate 404 ie ErrorDocument 404 `https://www.youdomain.something/errorpage.php`

Answer (score 6):

This is basically a canonicalizing URL prettifier that redirects clients to a shorter URL.

The `RewriteCond` operating on `%{THE_REQUEST}` is weird, since it works directly at the HTTP protocol level.  I understand that you want to avoid redirecting POSTs, since a redirect would convert POSTs into GETs, and such breakage would be an unacceptable consequence for having nicer-looking URLs.  However, it would be better to test `%{REQUEST_METHOD}` instead.

In the worst case, you could end up redirecting the client three times:

1. `GET /path/to/directory/index.php/`:
2. `GET /path/to/something/index.php`
3. `GET /path/to/something/index`
4. `GET /path/to/something`

By combining the first two rules, you could eliminate the third request.

```
# Strip off /index.php or /index or .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteRule (.*)(/index\.php|/index|\.php)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

In the trailing slash cleanup, you have a superfluous `RewriteCond`:

```
# Remove slash if not directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

I would tweak your last rule a bit.  Do the string analysis check before the filesystem check.  Use `$0` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1`.

```
RewriteCond $0 !(/|\.php)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

Comment: Can you please show me how it would look like all put together? I have tried to put them together but I am confused - I really don't know what I am doing